# Google play console statistics show numbers of installation in older version

Tags: android, installation, console, version

I have an android app, i released several versions like
1.0(5)
1.1(6)
1.2(7)
1.3(8)
1.4(9)

When i see in statistics->installe audience -> view by app version
i still see new installations happening on 1.0 and 1.1 version. how is it possible and how can they install those versions from?

Is there a way to see or stop users from installing 1.0 and 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Many sites scan the playstore and extract your app to their sites, storing each version you released. Some people might go on these sites to download your app.

One way to deal with this is to prompt the user to get the latest version of your app on start either by blocking the user with some "update required" screen , or just telling them that there is another more up to date version and redirecting them to the store if they want to